# How to allow one image to overflow out of the container and hide other when both images are over each-other?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
body{
    background-color:hsl(240, 73%, 65%);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
img{
    width: 90%;
}
h3{
    font-weight: 700;
}
p{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: smaller;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
hr{
    color: hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
}
.container{
    width: 800px; 
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
}
.images{
overflow:hidden;
}
.lady{
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;
    left: -50px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.box{
    width: 37%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: -70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper{
    padding: 5%;
}
.img-fluid{
    width: 2.5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}

.que:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
}

.font-toggle{
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <!-- Bootstrap link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 images">
        <img class="lady" src="images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="">
        <img class="box" src="images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 wrapper">
        <h3>FAQ</h3>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que"> How many team members can I invite?</div>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
        <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
          team members for the Premium plan.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
         <div class="que">What is the maximum file upload size?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
        <p>No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">How do I reset my password?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">Can I cancel my subscription?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>  Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">Do you provide additional support?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>  Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <div class="attribution">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: preview image of the design required]

I have applied the overflow:hidden property but it is cropping both the images. I want the lady(with laptop) image to be cropped(which is overflowing out of
the container) and show the box image, exactly as it is in the image.

Please see the preview image for reference.

I am stuck. Please help me out. I have just started learning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `lady` image into another div and set the overflow to hiddin in there.
Then position the `lady` using margins instead of `top` or `left`.  See here:

```css
body{
    background-color:hsl(240, 73%, 65%);
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}
img{
    width: 90%;
}
h3{
    font-weight: 700;
}
p{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: smaller;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 2%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
hr{
    color: hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
}
.container{
    width: 800px; 
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url("images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
}



.box{
    width: 37%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: -70px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper{
    padding: 5%;
}
.img-fluid{
    width: 2.5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}

.que:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
}

.font-toggle{
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ladywrap{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lady{
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <!-- Bootstrap link -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 images">
      <div class="ladywrap">
        <img class="lady" src="https://frontendmentor-faq-accordion-card.vercel.app/img/illustration-woman-online-desktop.44e30650.svg" alt="">     
      </div>
        <img class="box" src="https://frontendmentor-faq-accordion-card.vercel.app/img/illustration-box-desktop.a7ef46ea.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 wrapper">
        <h3>FAQ</h3>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que"> How many team members can I invite?</div>
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
        <p>You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on 
          team members for the Premium plan.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
         <div class="que">What is the maximum file upload size?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
        <p>No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">How do I reset my password?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page.A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">Can I cancel my subscription?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>  Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="question">
          <div class="que">Do you provide additional support?</div> 
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="">
          <p>  Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <div class="attribution">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image(lady one) is still not hidden. It is still there overflowing.

Comment: @PrachiRahangdale no it is not.  It is certainly being hidden. Run my snipped, you will see it is cut off while the box is outside and completely visible.

Comment: yes working thank you so much for your time